# Using bash to put API data into bash array

Tags: arrays, linux, bash

Using our new API I am trying to extract several lines from the results of the API call and put those results into a bash array. Can anyone help me with this please. This is an example of the API output:

```
{
    "id": "1l2k3j",
    "createDate": "2015-03-06T03:40:29.000Z",
    "accountId": "12345",
    "url": "www.google.com",
  },
  {
    "id": "z0x99c",
    "createDate": "2015-03-06T03:43:04.000Z",
    "accountId": "12345",
    "url": "www.yahoo.com",
  },
```

I need to put the ids (for example: z0x99c) into a bash array.

Comment: try searching answers here for `jsawk`. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
array=($(tr -d '",' < file | awk '/id:/ {print $2}'))
```

or with GNU sed:

```
array=($(sed -n 's/.*"id": "\(.*\)".*/\1/p' file))
```

or with GNU grep:

```
array=($(grep -oP 'id": "\K[^"]*' file))

echo ${array[@]}
```

Output:

```
1l2k3j z0x99c
```

Comment: I would have liked to do it with out exporting to a file, but this works. Thank you

Comment: Replace `file` by `<(your_command_writing_to_stdout)`.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you obtain this output,

```
array=($(curl http://api.example.com/boink | jq -r '.id'))
```

Comment: That may work! I do something very similar. I pipe it into a python parser to make it more human readable, but I guess that's no longer necessary in this case.

Comment: jq: command not found

Comment: It's not (yet!?) a standard utility, but it's widely available.  If you don't have it packaged for your platform already, it's a simple job to download and install it from http://stedolan.github.io/jq/

Comment: See the link to the proposed duplicate for a plethora of alternatives, including rolling your own JSON parser from an elephant's tusk and some second-rate paper clips.

Comment: How about python json parser?

Comment: curl http://api.example.com/boink | python -m json.tool